# change date format in flutter for json list particular data value

Tags: java, flutter, dart

this is working Because String

```
TimeUtils.convertddMMMyy( 
    DateTime.parse(lowprice.paidOn!)
        ),


 static String convertddMMMyy(DateTime date) {
    final DateTime dateTime = date;
    final DateFormat formatter = DateFormat('yyyy-MMM-dd');
    final String formattedDate = formatter.format(dateTime);
    return formattedDate;
```

I need  for a list , like below

```
CustomText(
    List[index].paidOn,
    color: ColorResource.appBarTextColor, ),
```

so how to change dateformat  in list for flutter  ?
now its giving 01-03-2022 i need 01-mar-2022

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's working now

```
CustomText(
    TimeUtils.convertddMMMyy(
    DateTime.parse(List[index].paidOn!)),
    color: ColorResource.appBarTextColor,
),
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried this way?

```
convertDateFormat(lowprice.dateFrom!, "dd-MMM-yyyy")
```

//

```
String convertDateFormat(String date, String new_format) {
    DateTime dateTime = DateTime.parse(date);
    return DateFormat(new_format).format(dateTime);
}
```